# Выбрать определенный объект в json

Tags: json, node.js

Есть *json* таблица такого типа:

```
attach:[{
    name: "z",
    color: "random1"
},{
    name: "L",
    color: "random2"
},{
    name: "J",
    color: "random3"
}];
```

Нужно получить значение *color* из объекта с *name* равным *J*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const attach = [
  {
    name: "z",
    color: "random1"
  },
  {
    name: "L",
    color: "random2"
  },
  {
    name: "J",
    color: "random3"
  }
];

// Находим элемент в массиве
const elem = attach.find(e => e.name === 'J');
// Если элемент найден
if(elem) {
    // выводим color
    console.log(elem.color);
}
```

[Документация к Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)